# Can I use annotation in django model like this and how?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

models.py

```
matches = models.ManyToManyField('Matches')
...
def get_rating(self):
  from django.db.models import Sum, Value, IntegerField
  from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

  return self.matches.annotate(rating=Coalesce(Sum('matches__rating_difference'), Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()) + Value(1000))
```

`rating_difference` contains player rating points

`get_rating` should return sum of points (player rating)

template.html

```
{{ player.matches.get_rating.(?)rating }}
```

Comment: What is `in_matches`?

Comment: why don't you try it? (you _can_ do it)

Comment: oops `in_matches` === `matches`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it works**

models.py

```
matches = models.ManyToManyField('Matches')
...
def get_rating(self):
  from django.db.models import Sum, Value, IntegerField
  from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

  return self.matches.aggregate(rating=Coalesce(Sum('rating_difference'), Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()) + Value(1000))
```

template.py

```
{{ player.matches.get_rating.rating_difference }}
```